# Configuring org-odt-export for emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode, odt

GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7)
Org-mode version 8.3.2 (org-20151005)

org-odt related config's in my .emacs:

```
;;ox-odt
```

`(require 'ox-odt)
;;/usr/share/emacs/site-list/org-mode/etc
(setq org-odt-data-dir "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/etc/org/styles")`

Styles folder contains:
1. od-manifest-schema-v1.2-os.rnc
2. od-schema-v1.2-os.rnc
3. OrgOdtContentTemplate.xml
4. OrgOdtStyles.xml
5. schemas.xml

Other .emacs config's set through M-x customize-variable RET 

`(custom-set-variables
 '(org-export-backends (quote (ascii html icalendar latex odt taskjuggler)))
 '(org-odt-convert-process "LibreOffice")
 '(org-odt-preferred-output-format "odt"))`

However when trying to convert cvArun.org file to odt through C-c C-e o O, mini buffer says -

`No such file: /home/deadlytackler/Documents/AKK/cvArun.odt`
Debug on error is enabled globally however it doesn't give any 'backtrace'. *Message* has following message -
`

```
    LaTeX to MathML converter not available.
    Formatting LaTeX using verbatim
    Wrote /tmp/odt-2666UgV/meta.xml
    Using vacuous schema [2 times]
    Saving file /tmp/odt-2666UgV/styles.xml...
    Wrote /tmp/odt-2666UgV/styles.xml
    Using vacuous schema
    Wrote /tmp/odt-2666UgV/mimetype
    Using vacuous schema
    Saving file /tmp/odt-2666UgV/META-INF/manifest.xml...
    Wrote /tmp/odt-2666UgV/META-INF/manifest.xml
    Saving file /tmp/odt-2666UgV/content.xml...
    Wrote /tmp/odt-2666UgV/content.xml
    (No changes need to be saved)
    Creating ODT file...
    Running zip -mX0 cvArun.odt mimetype
    Running zip -rmTq cvArun.odt .
    Created /home/deadlytackler/Documents/AKK/cvArun.odt
    Executing soffice --headless --convert-to odt --outdir /home/deadlytackler/Documents/AKK/ /home/deadlytackler/Documents/AKK/cvArun.odt
    Error: source file could not be loaded

    Export to /home/deadlytackler/Documents/AKK/cvArun.odt failed
    user-error: No such file: /home/deadlytackler/Documents/AKK/cvArun.odt
```

Any help in properly configuring org-odt would be highly appreciated, as unable to find what is stopping it to load source file (error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was recently troubled by the same error, setting

> org-odt-preferred-output-format

to either *odt* or *doc* resulted in the same error. *docx* seemed to work okay though. Found this out by running emacs with -Q and loading

```
(require 'ox-odt)
```

to remove my config out of the equation.